# rJava/JRI error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine

Tags: java, rjava, jri

Can anyone tell me more about this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine
    at DataMining.RunMinerBack.checkRLibVersion(RunMinerBack.java:643)
    at DataMining.RunMinerBack.init(RunMinerBack.java:831)
    at DataMining.RunMinerBack.<init>(RunMinerBack.java:126)
    at DataMining.ListMergeMembers.init(ListMergeMembers.java:1453)
    at DataMining.ListMergeMembers.<init>(ListMergeMembers.java:95)
    at DataMining.ListMergeMembers.main(ListMergeMembers.java:1585)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I have rJava installed, and I have JRI.jar in my CLASSPATH. I also checked and I do have Rengine.class in within JRI.jar, at the same path - org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.class. I'm not sure what/where else to check, so any suggestions would be appreciated.